# Property 'i' does not exist on type 'CustomGameComponent' after upgrade from Angular 8 to Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular10

This code compiled with no errors when I was using Angular 8.  I upgraded to Angular 10, created a new project and when I copy and pasted the code I get this error and the label on the input says "Player NaN". FormsModule and ReactiveFormModule is included in my app.module.ts.

Error Message:

```
src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.html:4:34 - error TS2339: Property 'i' does not exist on type 'CustomGameComponent'.

4             <mat-label>Player {{ i + 1 }}</mat-label>
                                   ~

  src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './custom-game.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomGameComponent.
src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.html:5:73 - error TS2339: Property 'i' does not exist on type 'CustomGameComponent'.

5             <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="players.controls[i]">
                                                                          ~

  src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './custom-game.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomGameComponent.
src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.html:7:65 - error TS2339: Property 'i' does not exist on type 'CustomGameComponent'.

7         <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="removePlayer(i)">
                                                                  ~

  src/app/features/modules/games/custom-game/custom-game.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './custom-game.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomGameComponent.
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="body">
    <div ngFor="let control of players.controls; index as i">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Player {{ i + 1 }}</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="players.controls[i]">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="removePlayer(i)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="addPlayer()">Add Player</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-game',
  templateUrl: './custom-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-game.component.scss']
})
export class CustomGameComponent implements OnInit {

  players = new FormArray([]);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addPlayer() {
    this.players.push(new FormControl(''));
  }

  removePlayer(index) {
    this.players.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use **let i=index;**

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
*ngFor="let control of players.controls; index as i"
```

not

```
ngFor="let control of players.controls; index as i"
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: that was it thank you for pointing that out.  That asterisk was in the old project and I copied and pasted the code without changing anything so I'm not sure how it disappeared.  Either way thank you.